# How to find the average value in a column of dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of 5000 records with a date column.

How do I find the average of those dates.  I've tried `AVG(datefield)`, but it says `Operand data type datetime is invalid for avg operator`

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/175-Ask-Ben-Averaging-Date-Time-Stamps-In-SQL.htm

Comment: Did you try to cast it as float and then use AVG ?I think it may works.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you want to average date only:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(datefield AS INT)) AS DATETIME) FROM dates;
```

And if you want to consider time:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(datefield AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) FROM dates;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a32af/1) to test.

Comment: I receive `
Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed.`

Comment: @Fka: Your table is using type `DATE` and not `DATETIME` as in this example. I suppose you would need to convert it to `DATETIME` first.

Comment: How can it be done with a `DateTime2` Type?  The same Cast generates an "Explicit conversion from data type datetime2 to float is not allowed." error.

Comment: If your table is using a date instead of a datetime, this works but looks even crazier: `SELECT CAST(CAST(AVG(CAST(CAST(dateColumn AS DATETIME) AS INT)) AS DATETIME) AS DATE) `

Answer (score 8):

For those of you getting a conversion error (can't convert date to int or float)...
Here's a simple solution using `datediff` and `dateadd`

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(DAY, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', datefield)), '1900-01-01') AS [AverageDate]
FROM dates;
```

Note that the January 1st 1900 date is arbitrary, it just has to be the same in both spots.

Answer (score 6):

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT, datefield))) as [AverageDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this and I hope it helps others in the future! SQL stinks for not making this easier.

```
Declare @Day as int;
Declare @Month as int;
Declare @Year as int;
Declare @Date as varchar(50);
SET @Day = (SELECT AVG(DAY(Column_name)) FROM Table_Name)
SET @Month = (SELECT AVG(MONTH(Column_name)) FROM Table_Name)
SET @Year = (SELECT AVG(YEAR(Column_name)) FROM Table_Name)
SET @Date =  CAST(@Day as varchar) +'-' + CAST(@Month as varchar) + '-' + CAST(@Year as varchar);
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2,@Date,103)
```