# How to store n number of SELECT results into variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So, i have this statement that returns OrderDates of all orders made by a customer. I'm trying to store the orderdates into a variable or multiple variable, to calculate average.

I know that for a specific result we can do something like this

```
DECLARE @tempvar DATE
SET @tempvar = (SELECT OrderDate From Orders WHERE CustID = '1234')
```

But issue is, what if select statement returns variable number of results (variable rows), like 0 results or 2 results or 4?

I know we can get number of rows returned by a select statement by `@@ROWCOUNT` variable.

To put my issue in simpler words, i need to store newest and oldest date returned by select statement, and divide it by number of rows returned.

Comment: go for procedure with table valued parameter or use CTE

Comment: What is your final requirement. Also could you please few sample rows and expected output you need.

Comment: Note about math: to calculate the average, you add (not subtract) the values and divide them by their count. Now back your question, calculating the average is easy to do in a query, so you don't need to do it by yourself. Tell us the column that you're trying to calculate its average so we can help you with the query.

Comment: @Shrey, You can not store multiple values in the variable instead you can use "Temporary table", "Temporary table variable" or "CTE"... One more thing, For which column you need to find the average - Order Date? Can you please provide sample data and expected output....

Comment: Use `Table Variables` or `Temporary Table` to store.

Comment: @RacilHilan, you're right, i'll edit that part. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main objective is to get the average of the dates, for that you don't need to store the dates to a variable, you can do it directly like following.

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(OrderDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) FROM Orders WHERE CustID = '1234'
```

You can also store the average of all date inside a variable, you can do it like following.

```
 DECLARE @AvgDate DATETIME
 SELECT @AvgDate =  CAST(AVG(CAST(OrderDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) 
 FROM Orders WHERE CustID = '1234'
```

Still if you want to store the dates into some variable, in that case to store more than 1 value better choose a table datatype as following.

```
DECLARE @OrderDates TABLE(OrderDate DATETIME)


INSERT INTO @OrderDates(OrderDate)
SELECT OrderDate From [Orders] WHERE CustID = '1234'

--TO GET AVG
SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(OrderDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) FROM @OrderDates ;
-- RETURNS ALL ROW
SELECT * FROM @OrderDates
```

Edit :

> To put my issue in other words, i need to get number of days between
>   highest and smallest date returned by SELECT statement

To find the days between MAX date and Min Date, you can do like following.

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day, MIN(OrderDate), MAX(OrderDate)) FROM @OrderDates
```

OR

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(day, MIN(OrderDate), MAX(OrderDate))   FROM Orders WHERE CustID = '1234'
```

Comment: So to calculate average, we need atleast two dates. So, what i need is, to get the earliest and latest date, get number of days between them, divide by number of rows (or number of orders).

Comment: I suggest you please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031850/how-to-find-the-average-value-in-a-column-of-dates-in-sql-server

Comment: That question is helpful, but that is Average of days. To put my issue in other words, i need to get number of days between highest and smallest date returned by SELECT statement. Cause i'm finding Average_Days per Order, not average date.

Comment: Oh my god, why didn't i think of this easy answer in the first place. Thanks a lot man. This helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this gets you what you want in just one line of code:

```
select dateadd(d, avg(datediff(d, '1970-01-01', OrderDate)), '19700101') from Orders where CustID = '1234'
```

In response to comment below, try:

```
select  
        dateadd(d, datediff(d, '1970-01-01', max(OrderDate)) - datediff(d, '1970-01-01', min(OrderDate)) / count(*), '1970-01-01') as requested_calc,
        dateadd(d, avg(datediff(d, '1970-01-01', OrderDate)), '19700101') as avg_date
    from Orders 
    where CustID = '1234'
```

But for the life of me, I don't understand why you would want this calc.  So I kept the other too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to store earliest and latest date returned by the SELECT statement, and divide it by number of rows returned. Your answer does seem compelling, but it still doesn't answer major concern, to get two dates, from select statement, and difference between them.

Comment: This does help @jwolf. Thanks :)